# Mutable Variables in Class __init__ Processing.py

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

```
class fish:

    def __init__(self,foods):
        self.foods = foods

    def log(self):
        print self.foods

dog = [10,20,30] 

f = fish(dog)

dog = [1,5,5]

f.log()
```

and when I run it instead of printing [1,5,5] it prints [10,20,30].  Is there any way for me to have f.foods update with the variable dog instead of having to write a new function in the class fish to update self.foods?

Comment: See e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a better understanding of what's going on. You could do `dog[:] = [1, 5, 5]` I suppose.

Comment: Variables are neither mutable nor immutable, it is the *objects they refer to* that would be mutable or immutable. But you *never* mutate any objects, `dog = [1,5,5]` doesn't mutate the list that `dog` was referring to (and is also referenced by `self.food`). Instead, it merely says "dog now refers to this other object"

Comment: What you are desiring to do is not a good idea anyway. The whole *point* of a class is to allow for the encapsulation of state, but here, you want to modify some global value to affect the state in your class. That is the poor design that classes are intended to *replace*.

Comment: You could also wrap the list in another list: `dog = [[10,20,30]]; dog[0] = [1,5,5]`. But agreed this is not a nice way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: Thanks, jonrsharpe, that page and your solution clear a lot up, especially since I'm a Python noobie.